# Bolzano's algorithm on Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am trying to code the bissection method on python, and I am having trouble applying it to different functions. So far I have this code:

```
def Bolzano(fonction, a, b, tol=0.000001):
   while abs(b-a)>tol:
       m=(a+b)/2
       if cmp(fonction(m))==cmp(fonction(a)):
           a=m
       else:
           b=m
   return a, b
```

This code doesn't work well because I don't know how to define the function. Writing simply

> Bolzano(3*x,0.5,1.0)

does not work because x is not defined. Because of this, I can't check if anything is wrong with the rest of the code.

Of course I could first define the function and then just apply it, but I want to be able to change the functions whils always keeping the same algorithm without rewriting it. Any help?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking, but have you tried `Bolzano(lambda x: x*3, 0.5, 1.0)`?

Comment: You can pass a function in as an argument, or use a lambda, as `Bolzano(lambda x: 3*x, 0.5, 1.0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lambdas](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html):

```
Bolzano(lambda x: 3*x,0.5,1.0)
```

Or define a function that you pass to `Bolzano`:

```
def f(x):
    return 3*x

Bolzano(f, 0.5, 1.0)
```

Then you can just keep adding functions:

```
def f(x):
    return 3*x

def f1(x):
    return 3*x+6

Bolzano(f, 0.5, 1.0)
Bolzano(f1, 0.5, 1.0)
```